# "Больше, чем из..." или "Из больше, чем..."

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как лучше построить фразу?

> Больше, чем из пяти тысяч участников...

или

> Из больше, чем пяти тысяч участников...

Или есть еще какой-то вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй вариант в принципе невозможен, предлог в русском языке не должен отрываться от существительного у (нас - от числительного). 
Первый в принципе допустим, но строго литературно: "**Более чем из пяти тысяч**".

Answer (score 0):

А что  - "из пяти тысяч"? Собрание, демонстрация? Или - было отобрано какое-то число "из"?
Если просто о количестве участников, то лучше, на мой взгляд, элементарное "Больше пяти тысяч".